# Using preg_replace and regex with varying formats

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have three types of strings that I encounter. My goal is to cycle through all of them and just get `name`.

```
page_1.name
page_2.name.text
page_1.name.something
```

The only way I can figure out doing this is to first remove the `page_#` with the following:

```
$remove_page = preg_replace("/(page_\d+\.)(\w+)/", "$2", $string);
```

Then remove the last bit like so:

```
$get_name = preg_replace("/(\w+)(\.\w+)/", "$1", $remove_page);
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? This works, but I feel like I'm only slightly grasping the power of regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
preg_match('/(?<=page_\d\.)[^.]+/', $input, $matches);
```

`(?<=page_\d\.)` is a lookbehind that makes sure our match is **preceded** by `page_` and a digit. `[^.]+` will match 1 or more characters that are not DOT.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fP3mC3/4)

Otherwise split by DOT and take 1st element:

```
$arr = explode('.', $input);
$name = $arr[1];
```

Comment: I added an explanation in answer.

Comment: Even `'/page_\d\.\K[^.\n]+/` regex will work where `\K resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match`